# With PyTest, run_until_complete does continue without finishing

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest

Basically, what it does, is to do 20 requests async to google.
If I launch it without using PyTest, just a snip of code, like this, it works:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def get(
    session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
) -> dict:
    url = f"https://www.google.com/"
    resp = await session.request('GET', url=url)
    data = await resp.json()
    return data

async def sessions():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(20):
            tasks.append(get(session=session))
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        htmls = loop.run_until_complete(sessions())
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print(htmls)
```

But when I use PyTest, in spite of being the same code (almost), the "htmls" variable at the end is not assignated any value

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get(
        session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
) -> dict:
    url = f"https://www.google.com/"
    resp = await session.request('GET', url=url)
    data = await resp.json()
    return data

async def sessions(self):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(20):
            tasks.append(self.get(session=session))
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

def test_example(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        htmls = loop.run_until_complete(self.sessions())
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print(htmls)
```

Why is this? It is like loop.run_until_complete(self.sessions()) is not waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Please don't include offers of payment, it's inappropriate. See: [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam)

Comment: ok. Don't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. It needed a self as first parameter for the get() method :S